# Is the Ito integral of a predictable process Gaussian distributed?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Let $(B_t)_{t\in [0,\infty)}$ denote the standard Brownian motion and $\mathcal F_t$ its filtration. Let $\Omega$ be the underlying probability space and $T>0$.

If $f\in \mathcal L^2[0,T]$, we may think of $f$ as a deterministic process $f\in \mathcal L^2([0,T]\times\Omega)$ with $f_t(\cdot)$ constant on $\Omega$. Then the Ito integral $W(f)$ of $f$ is Gaussian distributed, where
$$ W(f) = \int_0^T f_t(\cdot) \ dB_t$$
From the definition of the integral it is clear why: If we take a sequence $(f^{(n)})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of deterministic step processes (ie. step functions) converging to $f$ in $\mathcal L^2$, the partial integrals $W(f^{(n)})$ are sums of Gaussians, and therefore Gaussian (and convergence in $\mathcal L^2$ implies convergence in distribution, so the distribution of $W(f)$ is Gaussian since it is the $\mathcal L^2$ limit of $W(f^{(n)})$).

From one angle, the fact that $W(f)$ is Gaussian distributed relies on the fact that the changes in $f$ over time are independent of the changes in the Brownian. By contradistinction, $W(B_s) = \frac{1}{2}(B_T^2 - T)$ is not Gaussian distributed because the process $B_s$ is dependent on $B_s$.

What I'm wondering is whether the integral of *predictable* processes produces a Gaussian distributed variable. Why do I think it might? If $(a_t)_{t\in [0,\infty)}$ is a predictable process then, vaguely, the random changes in the Brownian in time interval $(t,t+\epsilon)$ are independent of what happened before time $t$, which determines $a_t$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Let $f_t = 1$ for all $t$ with probability $1/2$ and $2$ with probability $1/2.$ $f_t$ is previsible.  Then $W_T$ is a 50-50 mixture of normal with variance $T$ and $4T$, which is not a normal.

To put it a little more generally, it's true that the integral of a deterministic function is Gaussian with a variance that depends on the function, but then integral of a random function that is independent of the Brownian motion will have to be a mixture of normals with different variances, which are not necessarily normal. And there are plenty of random previsible processes that are independent of the Brownian motion.

Also, consider the [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_representation_theorem) that *any* Martingale can be written as the integral with respect to brownian motion of a previsible process.

Answer (score 7):

To follow up on spaceisdarkgreen's answer:

1. For any distribution on the real line there is an $\mathcal F_T$-measurable random variable with that distribution. (Even of the form $g(W_T)$ for an appropriate Borel function $g$.)
2. For any $\mathcal F_T$-measurable random variable  $Y$ there is a predictable process $H$ such that $Y=\int_0^T H_s\,dW_s$ a.s. This is a result of R.M. Dudley [Wiener functionals as Itô integrals; *Ann. Probability*  **5** (1977)  140–141; http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2242810.pdf].