# Let $X_t=\int_0^t \sigma (t)dB_t$. What is the law of $X_t$?

Tags: stochastic-processes

If $X_t=\int_0^t \sigma (s)dB_s$ is it possible to have information on the law of $X_t$ ? For example, if $h$ is very small, then $$X_{t+h}-X_t\approx \sigma (t)(B_{t+s}-B_t)\sim\mathcal N(0,t\sigma (t)^2).$$
Can we do better ?

I often heard that Itô integral $\int_0^t \sigma (t)dB_t$ can be seen as a local brownian motion with volatility $\sigma (t)$, but I'm not sure what it mean, any idea ?

Comment: Is $\sigma$ a (deterministic) function or a stochastic process?

Comment: @JasonSwanson: deterministic function.

Comment: In that case, $X_t$ is Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $\int_0^t\sigma(s)^2\,ds$.

Comment: Well remarked. Ok for expectation and variance, but how do you know that it will be gaussian ? And in the case where $\sigma (t)$ is random as well ?@JasonSwanson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\sigma$ is a deterministic function. The mean will always be zero by the mean value property of ito integrals. The variance is $\int_0^t \sigma(s)^2 ds$ by the Ito isometry. It is a gaussian random variable.

See: to show it is gaussian [The ito integral is gaussian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997061/the-ito-integral-is-gaussian)

Also, you can apply both arguments in the random process $\sigma(s,B_s)$

The result is mean zero and variance $\mathbb{E}\int_0^t \sigma(s, B_s)^2 ds$

But the distribution isn't necessarily gaussian:
Not necessarily gaussian: [Is the Ito integral of a predictable process Gaussian distributed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480786/is-the-ito-integral-of-a-predictable-process-gaussian-distributed)

Comment: That's indeed well remarked. Congrat. But how do you know that it will be Gaussian ? And in the case where $\sigma (t)$ is not deterministic ?

Comment: To show gaussian: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997061/the-ito-integral-is-gaussian

Comment: Think of it as a continuous  limit of discrete sums of gaussians

Comment: For the integral of a random process we take the expected value of the ito isometry to get the variance

Comment: But if $\sigma (t)$ is also random, does the ito integral will be Gaussian as well ?

Comment: Not necessarily gaussian: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480786/is-the-ito-integral-of-a-predictable-process-gaussian-distributed